# RegEx between two strings

Tags: regex

How would I get the "$0.00" in between this font tag?

```
<font color="#99002B">
$0.00
</font>
```

This is the only one on the page I want to get.

I really don't understand regex, so maybe someone could help whilst they answer too!

Thanks

EDIT:
The $ sign isn't always there either. It might be, for example;

`EUR 0,00`
`£ 4.44`

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Are you looking to get the $0.00 or the #99002B  value? Will you be wanting to get many other values for tags?

Comment: I'm using the PCRE library, so PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
/<font color="#99002B">\n?(.+[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\n?<\/font>/
```

Working demo: https://regex101.com/r/ME7QqL/1

If there are some more spaces around use:

```
/<font color="#99002B">\s*(.+[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\s*<\/font>/
```

Maybe you have to replace all `"\n"` by `""` before it works - haven't tested.

Comment: PHP has no `g`modifier.

Answer (score 0):

You've asked for a regular expression here, but it's not the right [**tool**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) for parsing HTML.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html); // Load your HTML data

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$node  = $xpath->query("//font[@color='#99002B']")->item(0);
echo $node->nodeValue; //=> "$0.00"
```

[Working Demo](https://eval.in/180047)

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/hapFEQ/1

```js
const pattern = /<font color="#99002B".*?>([\s\S]*?)<\/font>/i;
const match = `<font color="#99002B">
$0.00
</font>`.match(pattern);
const result = match ? match[1].trim() : '';
console.log(result);
```